# Any possibility of batch update using JPAUpdateClause in querydsl?

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

Is there any possibility of batch update using `JPAUpdateClause` in querydsl?

I found `SQLUpdateClause.addbatch()` only in an example while exploring the`JPAUpdateClause` class, but I didn't find any possibility of batch update. Can you suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

For batch updates use the EntityManager operations directly or JDBC.